# What is this thing inline with my dryer vent?

Tags: dryer

Just bought a condo with appliances included, and the dryer is underperforming. Went to check the vent hose and saw this:

[image: Dryer vent thing]

Comment: When you power up the external unit, does it whirr like there's a blower inside? Have you pulled the elbow off to see if the unit is clogged with lint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Acme Miami Model 9460 Dryer Vent Booster](http://www.acmemiami.com/dryerbooster.html)

If the vent has a long run to the external opening (up to 100 "effective" feet), this unit has a fan and a pressure sensor to automatically turn on when it senses dryer outflow to help push the exhaust air out.

When properly adjusted per instructions, the fan motor should come on when the dryer is in operation.

Comment: ...and you should replace all that crappy flex hose with solid metal dryer vent.